# Objective-c: serializing custom class objects in XML to save on disk and to send to server

Tags: objective-c, xml, xml-serialization, nscoding

I have been trying to do this for a week now... with no luck!

Object book:
String ISBN
int NumOfPages
String Title
String Author (etc.)

Object Library:
MuttableArray books

Now I need to write a method for the Object of class Library to write all the information of all the books in XML to the disk. This XML data is also needed to be sent over the network to the server. The server is running JAVA and I need to be able to work with Objects of classes Library and Book on the server too.

I here is what I have done up till now:
Class Book:

```
@interface Book : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property                   NSString            * title;
@property                   NSString            * author;
@property                   int                 * numOfPages;

@end
```

Class Library:

```
@interface Library : NSObject 

@property                   NSMuttableArray     * Books;
-(void) syncLibraryToFile;

@end
```

Comment: Can you send JSON instead?

Comment: yea... that is not a problem ... but I dont want to use third party plugins...

Comment: Why would you not want to use quality work done by other people?

Comment: well, I am afraid of its future... Whether it is still going to work in the next update... If it is pure Objective-C solution, then there are very high chances that the code won't break. It just helps me sleep at night better :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default archiver generates binary.  If you want XML, you have to change the output format.

```
NSMutableData *archiveData = [NSMutableData data];
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc]
    initForWritingWithMutableData:archiveData];
archiver.outputFormat = NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0;
[archiver encodeRootObject:self.Books];
[archiver finishEncoding];
```

Now you can send your `archiveData` to the server.  If you want JSON instead, it's easier still, and does not require a third-party framework.

```
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:self.Books
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:&error];
```

There are many options for writing data to disk, including the `NSData` methods

```
– writeToFile:atomically:
– writeToFile:options:error:
– writeToURL:atomically:
– writeToURL:options:error:
```

**EDIT**

In response to the question in the comments... you can easily write the data to a file...

```
[archiveData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

or

```
[jsonData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: but do I convert the object of class book to mutableDate? how?

Comment: could you please give me an approximate implementation of the method: syncFileWithCurrentCpStack ?

Comment: While the name is long, it's not intuitive what `syncFileWithCurrentCpStack` is supposed to do.  However, with the code provided, it should be pretty easy to grab whichever archive method you want to do and then just save the result to disk with one of the writeToXXX methods.

Comment: after [archiver finishEncoding] how am I supposed to write the XML to file? because the NSData methods are not available to archiver. I could use the class method +(NSData)archivedDataWithRootObject: to get the NSData object but then it has the binary format.

Comment: After archiving, the archived data is in the mutable data object you passed the archiver.  Since `NSMutableData` inherits from `NSData` you can use any of the "write" methods I mentioned at the end of the post.